# How to avoid jQuery mmenu scroll to top on opening

Tags: jquery-mobile, mmenu

I'm using mmenu context menu (comes from the bottom of the screen) on a list. when i'm scrolling down the page, and then fires the menu, on the open action the page is scrolled to the top. How can I avoid the scrolling?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You probably have `height: 100%` set on your `body` element. 
As stated [in the docs](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/support/tips-and-tricks.html),

> 2. Don't set a height on the HTML.

If you need a DIV to be (at least) 100% height, use

```
#my-div {
   height: 100vh;
}
```

This fixed the issue for me.